Can exterior paint overspray be removed from concrete surfaces?
I recently paid to have my house exterior painted and the contractor did not adequately control for overspray, and it is now all along my house along the bottom of the stucco and the concrete. Contractor says it can be cleaned, but I'm not sure how.

Any reason you don't hold them accountable?

Only pay the final amount once they have cleaned up. You did not pay in full did you....

"how" may involve solvents, sandblasting, ... and is their problem if they want the "job complete" payment. They could have masked.

The longer you wait, the harder it will be to remove latex paint. You may get it off by wetting it with straight soapy ammonia from a pump spray bottle, then scrubbing with a bristle brush, rinsing with a garden hose. Note that a pressure washer will make the concrete look "too clean" wherever it hits, and has a good chance of blasting stucco right off the house unless great care is taken. The painter is responsible, as others have pointed out.

I think it is ok for it to look "too clean". The concrete they oversprayed onto is actually only about 8 months old. Also, I have not paid in full. In actuality, I've only paid ~50% of the total cost so far. The next progress payment was supposed to be due, but I am withholding it for now until they fix this.

If it is on a non-painted surface then hot water - really hot - with some mild detergent and a brush will work.
If it is on a painted surface I honestly wouldn't touch it.   While it might drive you nuts if you are up close to see the overspray, trying to remove it will likely remove the original paint or some of it thereby compromising the surrounding paint.
Better solution is the painting company should be accountable for their mistake.   I would make them fix it...   It doesn't matter how hard that fix is.

Thank you. I am withholding final payment until that is fixed. So far, I've paid about 50% of the total cost. They are returning tomorrow to fix this, I am just unsure if it was possible or they were BSing me. It sounds like it is fixable, just not by me.
